# Delete characters until next '\n'

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm trying to epure my string from all the comments.
The comments in the code are indicated by ";" in front of the sentence.
And sometimes the end of the programs is indicated by ";;"

So imagine we have

```
push 34 ; example  
push 45  
add
```

In order to detect the occurence ";" I do this :

```
std::size_t findComment = _string.find(";");
```

I would like to be able to do this :

```
_string = _string.erase(findComment, '\n');
```

Delete everythin between the position and the first '\n'.

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE :**

I took the version of Konrad. It works well. But if the user write this on the standard output :

```
push int32(50)
push int32(50)
add
dump
;;
```

It should execute the function and display 100 (dump display the stack). But because it ends with ";;" the function trim_comments remove the function dump. So It isn't executed..

Comment: Just wondering, where do you get those strings from? If you get them from a stream, consider using `std::getline()` to split the string into lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find` has an overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) which lets you specify the start search position:

```
typedef std::string::size_type size_type;

size_type const comment_start = _string.find(";;");
size_type const newline = _string.find("\n", comment_start + 2);
if (newline == std::string::npos)
    _string.erase(comment_start);
else
    _string.erase(comment_start, newline - comment_start);
```

Furthermore, note the use of the `typedef` in the code above, your code is using the wrong type for the positions returned by `find`.

However, this code only removes a single comment. Removing several comments by iteratively `erase`ing from a string is quite inefficient. What you’d do instead is to build a brand new string from the non-comment fragments. To efficiently build up strings in C++, you use the [`std::[o]stringstream` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) instead of a bare `std::string`.

Here’s an example implementation which should work quite well:

```
std::string trim_comments(std::string const& code) {
    typedef std::string::size_type size_t;

    std::string const comment_start = ";;";
    std::ostringstream result;

    // Iteratively search for the start of the next comment and copy code before
    // that into the result.
    // We start by setting the previous comment end (the newline position) to
    // the start of the code.
    size_t newline_pos = 0;

    while (newline_pos != std::string::npos) {
        size_t const comment_pos = code.find(comment_start, newline_pos);

        if (comment_pos == std::string::npos) {
            // No more comments; copy the rest of the code from here until the
            // end into the result and quit.
            result << code.substr(newline_pos);
            break;
        }

        result << code.substr(newline_pos, comment_pos - newline_pos);
        // Find end of comment, assuming UNIX line endings.
        newline_pos = code.find('\n', comment_pos + comment_start.length());
    }

    return result.str();
}
```

You’ll notice that it’s quite a bit more complex than the previous, short code. This is the price we pay for correctness. A simpler solution requires more advanced text processing features, such as regular expressions (which are natively supported in C++11, and can be added to C++98 via libraries).

Comment: You **can** search the \n beyond the `;;` but why do use to start the search at the second semi-colon?

Comment: size_t returns a size_t http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ . Or do I miss something ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa What you’re “missing” is that cplusplus.com is a terrible reference, which contains lots of errors. This is one. Look at the link in my answer instead. cppreference.com is much more reliable: `std::basic_string::find` returns a `std::basic_string::size_type`.

Comment: Ow I did not know that. i only know C++ for a month, and during the adaptation pool they told us that it was the reference? Thanks. And what sould I do If I want to erase all the comments ? I guess it only works once no ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa To erase all comments, you can run this code in a loop until `comment_start` is `std::string::npos`. However, this is actually a fairly inefficient method for longer strings. A more efficient way is more convoluted and involves writing the results to a `std::stringstream` rather than repeatedly `erase`ing from the original string.

Comment: So `while (comment_start == std::string::npos)` ? (It doesn't delete comments) // `while (comment_start != std::string::npos) ` gives an infinite loop

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa Yeah, it’s a bit more complex than that. See update.

Comment: Thanks for the update it works very well. But I have a little problem . It's not ";;" to comment, it's only ";" so I changed it . It also works . But the problem is that I can also exit the program with ";;" and so if my string is `push int32(50) \n push int32(45) \n add \n ;; ` it removes `add` Any help ? See my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71423/discussion-between-nicolas-charvoz-kurzawa-and-konrad-rudolph).

Answer (score 0):

The `erase` method does the Job. All you Need it a second iterator for the `\n` Position.

```
// This code assumes that _string holds one line of the text.
std::size_t findComment = _string.find(";;");
std::size_t findNewLine = _string.find("\n");
_string = _string.erase(findComment, findNewLine);
```

If more than one line has to be processed use Konrads answer.

If you don't want to erase the new line character you can use `--findNewLine` before erasing.

Comment: This won’t work for the following: `_string = "foo\nbar ;;baz";`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::size_t commentPos = s.find(";;");
if (commentPos != std::string::npos) {
    std::size_t nlPos = s.find_first_of("\r\n", commentPos);
    if (nlPos != std::string::npos) {
        s.erase(commentPos, nlPos - commentPos);
    } else {
        s.erase(commentPos);
    }
}
```